# Boostrap modal-body content clean

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm stuck with a `Bootstrap` problem (or maybe directly with `jQuery`).

I've a `Rails` app. When it's on my test servers, there's not any problem. But this problem only appears in production.

Here is my problem.

On my modal, there is a `table` inside the `modal-body`.

When I click on the button (supposed to show the modal) everything is good for a second. Then my `modal-body` is cleaned up. I've added some logs on my production app. These logs come from all possible events bind on my `modal-body` element.
I've added 4 logs:

```
$('.modal-body').bind('blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup  mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error', (e) ->
  console.log this
  console.log $(this)
  console.log $(e)
  console.log   e
)
```

Here is my observation and screenshots.

In local (or test), `jQuery resize` method is called once and everything is fine.
[image: Resize only called once]

In production it's called twice.
[image: Resize called twice]
In this case, it seems that the first one clean up my `modal-body`. Then the second did its job normally.

Here is everything bound on my `modal-body`

[image: bounds]

Note : It's independent of the content of the `modal-body`.

Any idea?

Comment: Your `bind` code seems to be compiled 2 times. Try to unbind first.

Comment: I thought about that but when am I suppose to unbind it? On click on the button?

Comment: It depends where your `bind` context. Is it in a $(document).ready ? $(document).ajaxComplete ? on('page:load') ? Just put your all your console .log into a function x, then $('.modal-body').unbind('...', x).bind('...', x);

Comment: And which event am I suppose to unbind before binding it again? Can I  suppose that `resize` is the main event and nothing call it? The initialization is called on the $(document).ready.

Comment: I've added a screen of bound events on `modal-body`. `Resize` is bound only once..